# Cannot rename control to that of a control I deleted

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I'm having problems with two UserControls in VB.Net. I'm using VS2012. The UserControl is a panel called **DataDriver**, which at runtime is created dynamically on a form. Within **DataDriver** there is a control which is an instance of another UserControl defined in the project called **DataLink**. **DataLink** allows the user to select a data source (effectively a named connection string). Both the UserControls are defined in the same project.

At one point within the last 24 hours, I opened **DataDriver** in design mode and it showed me the screen I often get that states: "To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved: " with an "Ignore and Continue" link on it, which I clicked. I'm not entirely sure why this appears, but it does.

Once I'd opened **DataDriver** I found that the UserControl **DataLink** had disappeared. I created a new instance of it and tried to rename it to its original name (ucDataLink) with the error:

> Property value is not valid. There is already a component named
>   'ucDataLink'.  Components must have unique names, and names must be
>   case-insensitive.  A name also cannot conflict with the name of any
>   component in an inherited class.

I've closed the project, been through the three components of the UserControl **DataDriver** (the designer, the resx and the code) and removed any references to ucDataLink, and still is continues to raise this error. I can potentially use a different name, but this is the name that makes sense and I'd like to know how to resolve it.

Extra info. The **DataDriver** control is only instantiated at runtime. The form it is created in has a public method that is called. The form sets up the dynamic controls as below, and then shows using me.ShowDialog().

```
moActionEdit = New DataDriver
moActionEdit.Globals = g
moActionEdit.ConnectionName = mcConnectionName
moActionEdit.left = 0
moActionEdit.Top = 0
moActionEdit.width = pnl.Width
moActionEdit.Height = pnl.Height
moActionEdit.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top + AnchorStyles.Left + AnchorStyles.Right + AnchorStyles.Bottom
moActionEdit.Job = moJob
pnl.Controls.Add(moActionEdit)
moActionEdit.Visible = True
If Not moActionEdit.Init() Then
    moActionEdit.Visible = False
    Throw New DolphinException("Could not initialise data entry panel for this action type correctly.", True)
End If
```

How can I successfully rename my UserControl back to **ucDataLink**?

Comment: In Visual Studio you could use "Find in Files" to search for ucDataLink in all Files associated with your Project ... maybe you find it somewhere ...

Comment: Is this UserControl dynamic created in the load event of the form ? In that case it will be also created when you view the form in the designer. I solved that by ´if (DesignMode || LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime) {} `

Comment: @GuidoG - added some extra info to the question about how it is instantiated. DataDriver isn't instantiated in designing the main form. However, DataLink is instantiated in DataDriver when editing DataDriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Occasionally when you delete a control, it doesn't get deleted in the `.Designer` file. This isn't a particularly safe thing to do, so be careful.

In the **Solution Explorer**, click on the button to show all files.

Then also in Solution Explorer, click on the Right Arrow next to the form.

In the expanded list, you'll see a file that is something like `Form1.Designer.vb`

**I would strongly recommend making a copy of this file using Windows File Explorer before making any changes.**

Open this file and look for all the lines that contain the name of your deleted control and remove them. Save the file, and you should now be able to rename the new control to the same as the old one.

Comment: I had tried this several times using Notepad++ and found no trace of it. Having just tried again, I found that Notepad++ was searching in a case-sensitive mode and I was searching for "Datalink" and not "DataLink". Problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the accepted solution didn't work but something else did...

In the code there was a method that had the same name as a newly added menu (as I intended to use it for this new menu item):

```
Private Sub mnuViewZoom_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

I got rid of the error by first deleting the method and then recreating it e.g., by clicking on the menu in the designer view.

Hope that helps for others too.

Btw. I use Visual Studio Professional 2022.